# Small business / home network

Tags: networking, firewall, switch

Looking to make sure my configuration are correct. Need to set-up a small business network in a house. Equipment i have; cable modem, wireless router, hardware firewall running Linux/cent-OS, Cisco 48-port managed switch, Linux server. User desktop environment: Mac, Linux and Windows and a couple VMs running inside the windows machine. 
Is this configuration correct for max speed and security. Modem -> wireless router -> firewall -> managed switch -> server ??
Thanks

Comment: Need a Coffee Machine, otherwise looks good.

Comment: Devices connecting to the router via wireless won't be protected by the firewall.

Comment: Okay then is this the correct configuration: Modem ->  firewall -> wireless router -> managed switch -> server ?? Thanks

Comment: That would work.